# MVC Web App - How to allow users to use the virtual keyboard while Barcode Scanner is connected as physical keyboard?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I have a MVC Asp.net Web App I wrote using C# and Jquery. It is mainly being run on an android tablet.  My app relies on a bluetooth barcode scanner that is connected to the tablet ([Scanner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071FZBK2F)).

Users scan in barcodes to an inputbox that has focus into the webpage. Upon the box receiving the the scan with a carriage return it submits the form to the controller. Because I need that field to have focus I cannot  use a blur than focus method to hide the keyboard. Android identifies this as a physical keyboard.  When the scanner is connected the virtual on screen keyboard does not display.  This is fine as this is the behavior I would like. However at the bottom of my page there is a comment `TextArea` I have that I would like them to use the virtual keyboard for, but they cannot as the barcode scanner is still connected so it never pops up.

Is there some way to toggle the soft keyboard with Jquery?  The way I see it my options are:

- 1: Always have the keyboard show even when the scanner is connected
  and then somehow hide the soft keyboard via Jquery when the webpage
  enters "Scanning Mode"
- 2: Leave the keyboard as not showing up when the scanner is connected
  and somehow find a way to override the native function and bring up
  the keyboard via Jquery.

Either of these options will work or something else but I cannot figure out how to do either. I can't have the user toggling bluetooth on and off just to gain the physical keyboard back so I am looking for a software solution. Any advice would be appreciated a ton.

Comment: On focus use this: https://github.com/javidan/jkeyboard

Comment: Thanks @deblocker